# Problems with Cordova on Meteor fresh install

Tags: cordova, meteor

Using Windows, I run the Meteor installer and try to initialize via `meteor` on my command terminal. However, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\RandomUser>meteor
C:\Users\RandomUser\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.0-1\mt-os.windows.x
86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-common\node_m
odules\q\q.js:86
    hasStacks = !!e.stack;
                   ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

C:\Users\RandomUser>
```

I have not done anything. This error is occuring right out of the the box. I cannot even run a `meteor create`. This is a problem both on my regular CMD tool, as well as my Node.

Comment: You could try hard reset with `rm -rf .meteor/local`, but be careful data from your meteor mongodb also gets deleted.

Comment: Curious, how would I run that command? I am running on Windows, so instead of `rm` I hit `del` and everything else, but I get a `Invalid switch - "local"`

Comment: `rd /s /q .meteor\local` from Your meteor project

Comment: The problem though is that I can't initialize a Meteor project. My main Meteor install is causing this error. If I try to run a `meteor create project` I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries, I could solve the issue. It turns out that this is a problem of the Meteor itself, nothing to do with any App code.
So what I did is to uninstall Meteor, and then remove all folders of AppData/Local that meteor has created, basically they are in two folders: .meteor and Temp. Basically it seems that the uninstallation of Meteor is not 'clean' enough. 
After that, I installed Meteor again and everything works like a charm.